# Python reading in one line multiple types for a calculator

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm making a calculator where I the user will type something like 5 + 8 on a single line.

I know how to do this from a c++ viewpoint. How would I approach this from a python viewpoint. In c++ I would just use while cin

Resolved! Look in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python also you can use a loop and `input()`

```
lines = []
while <condition>:
    inp = raw_input()
    operand1, operator, operand2 = inp.split(" ")
    lines.append(inp)
```

EDIT: For a single line ...

```
inp = raw_input()
op1, operator, op2 = inp.split(" ")
op1 = int(op1)
op2 = int(op2)
# use op1, operator and op2
```

EDIT 2 : Converted input to raw_input as OP is using python2

Comment: Hi AJK. How would I set operand1 to 5, operator to +, and operand2 to 9? If for example in a line the user typed 5 + 9. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I tried what you said but I'm still having difficulty understanding. Could you perhaps look at what I have so far and tell me what I did incorrectly?

Comment: @mike you should use pastebin.org - it is very hard to edit code on screenshot.

Comment: Your code seems fine from first glance. is there any error it gives you ?

Comment: @mike  in Python 2.7 use `raw_input()`, in Python 3.x use `input()`. Both return string so you don't need `str()`

Comment: I posted a pastebin. I would like to thank you very much AJK for your help! This was driving me insane and the transition from C++ to Python has been a bit rough. Thank you so much!

Comment: @mike use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`

Comment: @mike, Yeah - you should use `raw_input` in python2 as @furas mentioned. Apparently in py2, if you put ` 3 + 5` input will automatically add it to give `inp=8`. I notice you're using prints without brackets, so im guessing you're using python2

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> s='5 + 8, 3 - 2, 9 + 4, '
>>> [eval(x) for x in s.split(',') if len(x.strip())>0]
[13, 1, 13]
>>>
```

Comment: Hi andre, I just listed some examples. 5 + 8, 3 - 2, 9 + 4 would all be on their own lines! I edited for clarity, apologies!